# /actuator/info Endpoint not working with spring boot 2.5.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I upgraded spring boot version in my app from 2.4.4 to 2.5.0 and it stopped exposing /actuator/info endpoint. Here is the pom.xml and application.yml

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ms</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <layers>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </layers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.yml**

```
management:
  endpoints:
    jmx:
      exposure:
        include: "health,info"
```

With spring boot parent version 2.4.4, the application is able to expose info endpoint but not with 2.5.0.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The correct property for exposing actuator urls over http is `management.endpoints.web.​exposure.include` (`web` instead of `jmx`).

In your case, `info` was exposed earlier not because you had the property you've provided but because it was exposed by default (along with `health`). But in **2.5.0** *it becomes hidden*, it according with [Spring Boot 2.5 Release Notes - Secure Info Endpoint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#secure-info-endpoint). So now you need to expose it manually.

Comment: +1 up for including the source, I upgraded to Spring Boot 2.5.9 from 2.4.12 and my /info stopped. I knew it became disabled but couldn't find the source.

Answer (score 26):

Add this to application properties to expose the /info endpoint.

```
management.info.env.enabled = true
```

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#actuator-env-infocontributor-disabled-by-default

Answer (score 12):

In my case, which was a silly mistake, I had the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Instead of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So I kept on getting Whitelabel Error Page 404 Not found on all /actuator calls

In application.properties

```
#Actuator
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=health,info,env,beans
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,env,beans
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to enable `management.info.env.enabled` `true` and you can add any kind of details that you want inside of the property file. like below. and make sure to enable `info` for web.exposure. all the configurations are like below.

---

### .properties

```
#enable /actuator/info
management.info.env.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info

#custom properties
info.app.name=order-service
info.app.version=1.0.0
info.app.description=you can insert any kind of data in the property file like this
info.author=mafei
```

### .ymal

```
#enable /actuator/info
management:
  info:
    env:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info

#custom properties
info:
  app:
    name: order-service
    version: 1.0.0
    description: you can insert any kind of data in the property file like this
  author: mafei
```

You can see the result here.

[image]

Comment: thx , I hv indented 'info' inside 'management' and wondered why it was not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic gradle build (kotlin dsl) to have three default available endpoints for actuator:

gradle.build.kts

```
build.gradle.kts
    //Global variables
    val junitVersion = "5.8.2"
    val springVersion = "2.6.4"
    val springWebVersion = "5.3.16"
    
    plugins {
        java
        id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.4"
    
    }
    
    group = "org.example"
    version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion")
        testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion")
    
        //spring boot
        implementation("org.springframework:spring-web:$springWebVersion")
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springVersion")
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:$springVersion")
        testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springVersion")
    
    }
    
    tasks.getByName<Test>("test") {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

application.yml

```
#tomcat
server:
  port: 7999

#actuator
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,info,env,beans
```

gradlew bootRun:

[image]

Actuator endpoint, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:7999/actuator/health
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check many things to be sure to endpoint URL like info, health, and beans...etc by Actuator

- The First point you must check if the actuator exists on your
  project or not if doesn't exist, you need to add the following
  dependency.

  ```
       <!--to enable actuator help to trace project-->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   </dependency>
  ```
- You need to add the following scripts to your application.yml to
  enable the actuator and Prometheus by actuator.

.

```
 management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  server:
    port: 9000
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
    health:
      show-details: always
      show-components: always
      probes:
        enabled: true
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
    info:
      env:
        enabled: true
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: prometheus, metrics, info, health, shutdown, beans
```

using the above script the actuator will run on **port 9000** and you can send a request to the following URL to access the actuator.

http://localhost:9000/actuator

**and the following URL to access info path**

http://localhost:9000/actuator/info

**Note**: you must check where you are writing your script because I was confused between **endpoint** and **endpoints**

- The **endpoint** to set the actuator config.
- The **endpoints** to set the actuator **URLs endpoint**

**Note:** you can delete the port from  `application.yml` and the actuator will run by current application port

**best luck**