# Exposing Spring boot actuator endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to expose Spring boot actuator endpoints env and info.

I have a very basic demo application and don't have Spring security in my classpath.

I am on 2.7.1 spring boot version.

I have added this property in the app.properties file

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=env,info
```

In the pom.xml i added

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But i don't get the endpoints at /env and /info. Instead i get 404.

I followed this SO post [/actuator/info Endpoint not working with spring boot 2.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893857/actuator-info-endpoint-not-working-with-spring-boot-2-5-0) but it also did not help much.

**UPDATE**

It worked if i lowered the spring boot version to 2.4.3  and corresponding spring cloud dependencies.

Not sure what is the issue with my current version 2.7.1
Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Check that your `app.properties` file is actually read by Spring (by default it should be named `application.properties`). Also add `debug=true` to the properties and post the log that shows up after you send a request to the actuator endpoint.

Comment: Yes...sorry my bad...in a hurry i mentioned app.properties..but its application.properties...its read as well since i am controlling other configuration through this file

Comment: Please check the update made above in the post

Comment: The endpoints will be available at `/actuator/env` and `/actuator/info` by default. Did you try to access them at `/env` and `/info`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to see if the endpoint `/actuator` returns some content. If it **does not return anything**, then the actuator is not correctly plugged in and there might be some dependency issue or version missmatch in your project.

If `/actuator` returns a response, then you can try the following:

Although the following properties are by default set to `true` there might be some complex configuration that disables those endpoints for your project.

Try to set them to enabled by explicitly stating this in `application.properties`.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,env
management.endpoint.env.enabled=true
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
```

Comment: I know i am sounding stupid :)...but now it works with 2.7.1 also with /actuator endpoints.