# How to display app version in actuator/info using Spring Boot and app.yml?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Maven for Java project with Spring Boot and Actuator.

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I would like to bring back the Snapshot version in pom.xml of the project in /info tab and read many tutorials on the subject like those above.

1. https://blog.jdriven.com/2018/10/get-your-application-version-with-spring-boot/
2. https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-version/
3. [/actuator/info Endpoint not working with spring boot 2.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893857/actuator-info-endpoint-not-working-with-spring-boot-2-5-0)

app.yml:

```
#general properties
management:
    endpoint:
        info:
            enabled: true
    endpoints:
        info:
            enabled: true
#custom properties
info:
    app:
        name: Spring Sample Application
        description: "spring application
        version: '1.0.0'"
```

I did not know which quotes to use in my app.yml.

But I never succeed to display anything in the /info tab, there is just those { } symbols.

Anyone knows what I did wrong and how to display my app version in /actuator/info?

Comment: You need to enable the buildInfo in your build so it will get added to the properties 9Not the yaml) (which is basically the second tutorial). Please include your build file to see what you are doing there. There is also a section in the Reference Guide (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.build.generate-info).

Answer (score 1):

Use @project.version@

```
info:
  app:
    name: '@project.name@'
    description: '@project.description@'
    version: '@project.version@'
```

This will be replaced with the Maven version

Comment: It did not work for me. I'm not able to display any informations (name, description, version) in my YML.

Comment: This works as in my answer. You must run mvn compile. If you just start the app from your IDE there will be no substituiion

Comment: This only works if the maven resource plugin is configured to substitute the '@xxx@' placeholders. Usually through the `<filtering>true</filtering>` in the build>resources sections. (it's false by default)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for Spring Boot 3 Application**

1. You need to add the following dependency to the `pom.xml` file of your application;

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Then, you should add the following code block to the `application.yml` file.

> You can customize the information under the `info:` section according to your preferences.

```
management:
  info:
    env:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info
      base-path: /public/actuator

info:
  application:
    name: '@project.name@'
    description: '@project.description@'
    version: '@project.version@'
```

3. If you are not using Spring Security, you can skip this step. You need to expose the `/public/**` endpoints specifically for the `GET` HTTP method. Otherwise, you will get an error because you won't be able to access these endpoints.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) {

   httpSecurity
      ...
      .authorizeHttpRequests(customizer -> customizer
         ...
         .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public/**").permitAll()
         ...
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
      )
      ...

   ...
}
```

4. After completing the first and second steps, you can start the application and test it by accessing the `{{API_URL}}/public/actuator/info` URL in a browser.

> Example for {{API_URL}}: http://localhost:8080